# MVC 4 - Why is my body getting set to 1903px x 300px?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I've created an MVC 4 app (Internet template). The body it created is 1903px wide by 300px tall. In the image below, you can see how it's being rendered. I don't see anywhere where a width is being specified, and I'm curious as to why it decided to create a width of 1903px (and a height of 300px).

[image]

If it helps, the HTML of the main page looks as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - The Exchange Site</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <img src="~/Images/CompanyLogo.png">
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">
                        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                    </section>
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Siesta Key Software, LLC</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ExchangeSite")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"The body it created is 1903px wide by 300px tall"_ - where do you see that? Do you have the same issue when rendering without both `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")` and `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")`?

Answer (score 0):

I've just had exactly the same issue / question. It is setting the width based on the width of the browser window. If you make your window narrower and refresh the screen you will see that the width property (and probably the height property) have changed. I got around this by explicitly setting the width in the Site.css of the body as follows :

```
body {
    width:2000px;
}
```